# Almost got material ui to work but still can't render anything

Tags: reactjs, materialize, material-ui

So I reactified the test.jsx file but instead of rendering the raised button I'm getting  ``(two quotation marks at the top of the page). Console.log is not giving me any errors so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <title>A Simple HTML Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>``
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>HTML is Easy To Learn</h2>
  <p>Welcome to the world of the 
  World Wide Web.
  This is the first paragraph. 
  While short it is still a paragraph!
  </p>
  <div id='main'></div>
  <script script"build/test.js"></script>
  <p>And this is the second paragraph.
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

test.jsx

```
    var RaisedButton = require('./RaisedButton.jsx');

React.render(<RaisedButton />, 
    document.getElementById('main'));
```

raisedButton.jsx

```
var RaisedButton = React.createClass({

  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
    };
  },

  render() {
    return (
        <RaisedButton label="Default" />
    );
  }

});

module.exports = RaisedButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're exporting RaisedButton and using it at the same time, I've never seen that before. Try changing

```
  render() {
     return (
       <RaisedButton label="Default" />
     );
  }
```

To:

```
  render() {
     return (
       <button label="Default" />
     );
  }
```

Based on your code sample, this is what I think your issue is.

Comment: He's specifically using material-ui components so why would you use <button /> ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your jsx file:

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'

render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <RaisedButton label="Default" />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
}
```